# meta/prefs.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, c++

I tried to a code derived from [this code](https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/blob/wip/xinput2/src/core/core.c#L824), but I got an error in QtCreator:

```
error: meta/prefs.h: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the development package `libmutter-dev` via

```
sudo apt-get install libmutter-dev
```

---

*Why? This is why.*

```
% apt-file search meta/prefs.h
libmuffin-dev: /usr/include/muffin/meta/prefs.h
libmutter-dev: /usr/include/mutter/meta/prefs.h
```

and because we talking about `mutter`

```
mutter/src/core/core.c
```

`libmutter-dev` is correct.

Comment: thanks. I checked the link you gave in the other answer and libmutter-dev was listed there.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer, I should not answer questions on mobile o_O